# How to make a block appear in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsfiddle

Hi and thanks for the great work here. I'm pretty new in reactjs and I'm struggling to make it work with sandbox like jsfiddle.

I have a div called "app-content" tht is supposed to appear in the middle of the document just like the following : [image]

For some reasons , I cant make the following thing on my sandbox , and I get the following : https://jsfiddle.net/w7sf1er6/8/

JS here

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
    <div className="app-content">
    </div>
        );
    }  
};

ReactDOM.render (
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and CSS here

```
html {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  font-family: regular, arial, sans-serif; }

body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }

.app-content {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: white; }
```

What am I mising ? I need to make it work on JSfiddle so I can share it with others developers. I wuld appreciate some help from our community.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems fine. You had an incorrect setup on jsFiddle. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eo1qppo0/

Comment: @Chris Thanks. Also how can I cancel the top margin that appear on the top of the block just like in my picture ? For some reason I cant reproduce the same error in a sandbox

Comment: inspect your `html` and `body` tags. They are likely to have `padding` or `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

You must install react-blocks via `npm` first if you haven't already.

Like so,    `npm install react-blocks`

Once you have done this, you will need to import/require react-blocks within your react code.

```
    // using an ES6 transpiler 
import Block from 'react-blocks';

// not using an ES6 transpiler 
var Block = require('react-blocks');
```

Next, the layout:

```
// Normal Flex layout 
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Block layout>
      <div>Alpha</div>
      <div>Beta</div>
    </Block>
  );
};

// Reverse Flex layout 
const Reverse = () => {
  let { reverse } = styles;
  return (
    <Block style={reverse.block} layout vertical reverse>
      <div>Alpha</div>
      <div flex>Beta</div>
    </Block>
  );
};
```

Feel free to read more on the process [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-blocks).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your React component is not rendering to the div. You can see errors in the console log and doing "view frame source" on the HTML output pane will show you that the "div" element hasn't been replaced.

As Chris suggested, just start from a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) that sets up React correctly.

The example above mainly differs from your code in that it imports React definitions.

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js" />
```